# What ping ping localhost does?

Tags: linux, networking, ping

While I was working I made a typo and I did execute

```
ping ping localhost
```

and I got

```
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(124) bytes of data.
```

with 100% packet loss. Obviously, if I type

```
ping localhost
```

the output

```
PING localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
```

all packets are received.

My question is: what ping ping localhost exactly does? How are parameters interpreted? why packet loss?

thanks

Comment: What version of Linux are you using that did this?

Comment: I work with Fedora 20 and ping utility, iputils-s20140519
 , but Debian has the same output. By the way, I have tried with Fedora 23 and last ping version (ping utility, iputils-s20150815) and it drops: http://pix.toile-libre.org/upload/original/1453159993.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you `man ping` for your version, you'll see that one of the options is the `hop` option (`ping [hop ...] destination`), this lets you ping your destination through the `hop` and is useful if you have multiple gateways and want to explicitly tell the route of the ping.

So `ping ping localhost` is going to ping `localhost` while using `ping` as it's `hop`. But the real question is why does `ping ping` work and not return an `unknown host` error? It should be noted that doing a `ping ping` on Windows and some variations of BSD return the `unknown host` error, but not for the reasons one might initially think.

If I do a `ping ping` on my system, I get back `127.0.53.53`, and after some poking around, I found a [related answer](https://superuser.com/questions/958758/why-pinging-drive-gets-replies-from-127-0-53-53) that helps to explain this result; in a nutshell it has to do with the DNS server you're using and ICANN's naming collision framework, which gives back the address of `127.0.53.53` for certain generic TLD's (`ping` being one apparently). Some OS's and versions of the `ping` utility might append a TLD (or your local domain) to the destination for you, so if you did `ping ping`, it could actually do a `ping ping.com` or `ping ping.localdomain` and return the results expected (vs. giving `127.0.53.53`).

That should help explain why you see packet loss when you do `ping ping localhost`; you're routing your pings through your `localhost` to ping your `localhost`, which if your system is not setup to do that (route ping requests), it will fail and give back the packet loss that you're seeing.

Hope that can help.